# Converting from 4 inch to 3.5 inch iphone displays

Tags: ios, user-interface, screen-size

I have an app I have been developing for a long while now.  It is very complex, uses cocos2d and has lots of intricately arranged display elements.  It is nearly finished now, save for game balancing, play testing & maybe some more debugging.  The problem is the interface is completely optimized & designed for a 4 inch display.  I probably should have incorporated more flexibility as I was going along, but made the incorrect assumption that I could support 4 inch and greater screens only and still be accepted by the app store, but apparently that is an illusion.

Given my current situation, is there any easy way of adjusting my interface?

Comment: You have 88 additional (non-retina) pixels in your UI. You can hide the status bar if you don't already, saving 20 pixels. If you show ads, you might consider simply not showing them on  3.5" screens - that will save you 50 pixels in portrait mode. Not sure where you can get the remaining 18 pixels - can you simply lop off 9 at the top and bottom or tighten the spacing a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Slect the view controller and enable the auto layout.And select the all controls in main view and right click the resolve layout option at bottom and select the "Add missing constaraints".That's it